# Running a shell script with and without "bash" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have a script that runs fine when I add the "bash" in front of it,

`bash ./myscript.sh /opt/config/run.config`

but when I don't it stops at the below line and exits.

`source "/opt/config/test.config"`

No problems when I append the bash in front of the command.

Is there anything in the environment variables that I have missed as I'm setting up a new box. The same script doesn't have any issues on the older boxes.

Comment: Is the script executable, does it have a `#!`-line pointing to the correct interpreter? Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Kusalananda I dont get any error message, i just stops and exits when I dont run this with bash in the front.

Comment: Show the whole script, please. And please answer Kusalananda 's question: Do you have a shebang line (#!) and what is it? Probably, your default shell is not bash, but something that does not understand 'source' tje way bash does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution: add the shebang `#!/bin/bash` at the head of the script

You can force using the shell you want with the first line: `#!/bin/bash` which is another way of doing what you do with `bash ./myscript ...`

```
#!/bin/bash

...
...
source "/opt/config/test.config"
...
...
```

### Possible explanation of your problem

There is no `source` built-in command in the shell `sh` (and there is no program with the name `source`). So if your script is run by `sh`, it will fail at the command line with `source`.